# Apple In App Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app with version 1.2 on the App Store and it's also been accepted by Apple. I have added In App Purchases to the app, also tested these in the sandbox.

Now I have uploaded the same binary for review to Apple that contains the In App Purchases.

My binary seems to have the correct status 'Waiting For Review' but my In App Purchases are still showing 'Ready To Submit' and I can't see any option to submit them.

Am I doing something wrong, or will Apple automatically change the In App Purchases' status to "Ready For Sale"?

Comment: This is not the correct site to ask this question. You should contact Apple's market support.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem regarding your contract (might not be valid)

Answer (score 0):

If these are your first in app purchases for this app they need to be selected when submitting the binary for review. See Apple's guide linked below.

[Submitting Your First In-App Purchase Product](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH5-SW1)